# DHCP connection with an always-available additional static IP via NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

I'd want an equivalent of the following `/etc/network/interfaces` config, but done via NetworkManager (or at least giving me chance to control eth0 connections via nm-applet and possibly choose a different one):

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The static address is from a different subnet than the one from DHCP.

The closest I could get with NetworkManager was to create a connection on eth0 with "Auto" type, and added an additional IPv4 address (either via nmcli or nm-connection-editor).

The problem is that until the interface gets a DHCP lease, the static address is not available. That's a big problem in my setup - there are cases where the DHCP server will never be available and I need to have at least the static address.

Even setting `may-fail` doesn't help, since it skips the whole IPv4 configuration if no lease is available.

I also tried to put just the subinterface `eth0:1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but as soon as I connect and disconnect the NetworkManager-managed DHCP connection, the subinterface gets lost. So I tried creating post-up and down scripts which bring `eth0:1` up/down. But that results in weird behavior - NetworkManager then automatically creates a new connection called `eth0` with just a static address and "Manual" setting. It's not set to autoconnect, though the system connects to it as soon as it figures out that the DHCP lease won't come. And once the system is connected to this "surprise" connection, it will never try to reconnect to the one with DHCP.

Comment: Did you meanwhile succeeded somehow with this? I have the same problem, searching for an answer

Comment: Yes. See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is pretty close to what I want - only the static IP is not configured by NM. But that's not a big problem as the eth0 normal connection remains fully manageable by NM and that was the main point.

Add this "empty" interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` and utilize pre-up/post-down to add an L2 IPVLAN link to eth0:

```
auto internal
iface internal inet manual
  pre-up /sbin/ip link add link eth0 name internal type ipvlan mode l2
  post-down /sbin/ip link del internal

  up /sbin/ip address add 192.168.1.115/24 dev internal
  down /sbin/ip address del 192.168.1.115/24 dev internal
```

You then get virtual interface `internal` (some tools report it as `internal@eth0`) which is started when the computer boots. All the time you have this interface, the static IP works, regardless of the DHCP status on eth0. You can do whatever you want with eth0 in NM.

This was tested to work very reliably for a few years on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -1):

RTFM dude.... on my Debian:

1. `man 8 NetworkManager`

```
DISPATCHER SCRIPTS
       NetworkManager will execute scripts in the
       /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory or subdirectories in
       alphabetical order in response to network events. Each script should be
       a regular executable file owned by root. Furthermore, it must not be
       writable by group or other, and not setuid.

       Each script receives two arguments, the first being the interface name
       of the device an operation just happened on, and second the action. For
       device actions, the interface is the name of the kernel interface
       suitable for IP configuration. Thus it is either VPN_IP_IFACE,
       DEVICE_IP_IFACE, or DEVICE_IFACE, as applicable. For the hostname and
       connectivity-change actions it is always "none".

       The actions are:

       pre-up
           The interface is connected to the network but is not yet fully
           activated. Scripts acting on this event must be placed or symlinked
           into the /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d directory, and
           NetworkManager will wait for script execution to complete before
           indicating to applications that the interface is fully activated.

       up
           The interface has been activated.
```

2. Create a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` that will:

   - Check if `$1 == "eth0"`
   - Check if `$2 == "up"`
   - If so, call `ifconfig eth0 add <your second IP>`

Comment: I'm not sure you got what the problem is. I need the static address to be present even in case th DHCP server doesn't respond. But the up event is only generated when the DHCP connection succeeds...

Comment: Then try the `pre-up` step.

Comment: pre-up resulted in the same behavior (it might seem odd, but that's the reality)